# Df.mean returns imaginary numbers

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with around 50 columns and around 3000 rows. Most cells are empty but not all of them. I am trying to add a new row at the end of the dataframe, with the mean value of each column and I need it to ignore the empty cells.

I am using df.mean(axis=0), which somehows turns all values of the dataframe into imaginary numbers. All values stay the same but a +0j is added. I have no Idea why.

```py
Turbine.loc['Mean_Values'] = Turbine.mean(axis=0)
```

I couldnt find a solution for this, is it because of the empty cells?

Comment: Well presumably because you have some imaginary numbers in the dataframe, and in order to compute the mean it is cast to `complex`

Answer (score 0):

Base on [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html), `df.mean()` will automatically skip the NaN/Null value with parameter value of `skipna=True`. Example:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'value':[1,2,3,np.nan,5,6,np.nan]})
df=df.append({'value':df.mean(numeric_only=True).value}, ignore_index=True,)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   value
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    NaN
4    5.0
5    6.0
6    NaN
7    3.4
```

But if there is a complex number in a cell, the result of `df.mean()` will be cast to complex number. Example:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'value':[1,2,3,np.nan,5,6,np.nan, complex(1,0)]})
print(df)
print('\n')
df=df.append({'value':df.mean(numeric_only=True).value}, ignore_index=True,)
print(df)
```

Output with a complex value in a cell:

```
    value
0  (1+0j)
1  (2+0j)
2  (3+0j)
3     NaN
4  (5+0j)
5  (6+0j)
6     NaN
7  (1+0j)


    value
0  (1+0j)
1  (2+0j)
2  (3+0j)
3     NaN
4  (5+0j)
5  (6+0j)
6     NaN
7  (1+0j)
8  (3+0j)
```

Hope this can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

some cells had information about directions (north, west...) in them, which were interpreted as imaginary numbers.